# Haskell Translation Task

Tags: haskell

I'm new to programming, and I'm having trouble solving a task.

I have to use the function. In that case I have to implement it on a triangle.

I've tried different things but I'm just getting errors and that's why I'd like to ask for help.

```
data Triangle = Triangle {
  tP1 :: Point,
  tP2 :: Point,
  tP3 :: Point}
  deriving (Show)
```

Comment: You have to return a single `Point`, which is just a tuple `(x, y)`. What's `x`, and what's `y`, when given a triangle and a vector?

Comment: I think perhaps `translatePol` should have the type `p -> VectorD -> p`.

Comment: It's simpler, though, if you write an instance for `Point` first (though that will require using `data` instead of `type`); you can use that to construct a new triangle by translating each point separately.

Comment: You forgot to write the constructor `MTriangle` when you are creating the new triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, points and vectors are two separate concepts, and should probably be distinct types, not just two different aliases for a 2-tuple.

```
data Point = Pt Float Float
data Vector = V Float Float
```

Second, your type class seems to capture the idea of translating collections of points using the same vector. The return type should then be the same as the first argument type, not hard-coded to `Point`.

```
class Polygon p where
    translatePol :: p -> VectorD -> p
```

Now you can start simple, and define a `Polygon` instance for `Point`. (Think of a point as a degenerate polygon.)

```
instance Polygon Point where
    translatePol (Pt x y) (Mvector v1 v2) = Pt (x + v1) (y + v2)
```

This can be used to define the instance for `Triangle` more simply.

```
instance Polygon Triangle where
    translatePol (MTriangle p1 p2 p3) v = MTriangle (t p1) (t p2) (t p3)
        where t p = translatePol p v
```